# Is there a way to search other than by primary key

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm coding an asp.net web api which will access data held on a mysql database.  I am able to search for specific details through 'api/company/{company id number} which shows its working.

However what I'm wondering is whether there is a way to return a result based on {company name} rather than the primary key {company id}.

My reason for this is that the search query is more likely to be based on trying to find a company record by name rather than by company id.

Sorry if i sound like a noob, that's because I am.

I've tried changing (int id) to (string id) but that simply throws an error as its searching through the primary key field which is type int.

```
public class companyController : ApiController
{
    private apollodbEF db = new apollodbEF();

    // GET: api/company
    public IQueryable<companydetail> Getcompanydetails()
    {
        return db.companydetails;
    }



    // GET: api/company/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(companydetail))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getcompanydetail(int id)
    {
        companydetail companydetail = db.companydetails.Find(id);
        if (companydetail == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(companydetail);
    }

public class companyController : ApiController
{
    private apollodbEF db = new apollodbEF();

    // GET: api/company
    public IQueryable<companydetail> Getcompanydetails()
    {
        return db.companydetails;
    }



    // GET: api/company/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(companydetail))]
    public IHttpActionResult Getcompanydetail(string id)
    {
        companydetail companydetail = db.companydetails.Find(id);
        if (companydetail == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(companydetail);
    }
```

Comment: I believe that something, essential to a key being a primary key, is that each primary key is unique for an entity. In other words, no other entity can have the same primary key as a certain entity. But hey, you could find entities by using other properties of it, i.e. the employee count of a company. A risk that could occur in this scenario is that you could find multiple companies, because the employee count is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: You are not limited to use Find. There are other methods that allow you to search using any property in the object _companydetail_ For example FirstOrDefault

Answer (score 4):

You can use a where statement

```
var company = db.companydetails.Where(c => c.Name == "My Company").FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: There's no need for both the `Where` **and** the `FirstOrDefault`, just put the lambda inside the `First`. e.g. `var company = db.companydetails.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Name == "My Company");`

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for that.  I tried the Where clause but i had written it out wrong, made it more complicated than it needed to be.